# how to use multiple prepared statements with multiple if conditions in servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee

```
PreparedStatement ps=Database.con.prepareStatement("select * from account where accountno='"+accno+"' and password= '" +pass+ "'");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        PreparedStatement ps1=Database.con.prepareStatement("select * from apass where accountno='"+accno+"' and OTP= '" +pass+ "'");
        ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
        PreparedStatement ps2=Database.con.prepareStatement("select * from account where accountno='"+accno+"'");
        ResultSet rs2=ps2.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300);
        session.setAttribute("name",rs.getString("full_name"));
        session.setAttribute("mbno",rs.getString("mobileno"));
        session.setAttribute("pass",rs.getString("password"));
        session.setAttribute("accno",rs.getString("accountno"));
        response.sendRedirect("PBank.jsp");
        }
        if(rs2.next())
        {
            String pas=rs2.getString(6);
            if(pas==null)
            {
                response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?messageInactive=You have deactivated your account, kindly activate your account to login!!");
            }
        }
        if(rs1.next())
        {
           session.setAttribute("accno",rs1.getString("accountno"));
           session.setAttribute("pass",rs1.getString("OTP"));
           response.sendRedirect("reset.jsp");
        }
       if(pass.equals(passs) && accno.equals(acc))
       {
            session.setAttribute("passs",passs);
            session.setAttribute("acc",acc);
            response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
        }
       else
       {
           response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?message=Incorrect Account Number or Password!!!");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructs as follows:

```
    try (PreparedStatement ps = Database.con.prepareStatement(
                "select full_name, mobileno, password, accountno "
                + "from account where accountno=? and password=?")) {
        ps.setInt(1, accno);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300);
                session.setAttribute("name",rs.getString("full_name")); // Or (1)
                session.setAttribute("mbno",rs.getString("mobileno"));// Or (2)
                session.setAttribute("pass",rs.getString("password")); // pass
                session.setAttribute("accno",rs.getString("accountno")); // accno
                response.sendRedirect("PBank.jsp");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

- **PreparedStatement *with* placeholder `?`** which prevents [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) and escapes `'` and such. And you can use types.
- **try-with-resources** that `close` statement and result set automatically, even on exceptions and returns.
- In SQL `select *` here would be okay, but for lists better select a restricted number of columns, which is faster and uses less memory.
- The password handling: better to not store it as attribute. Also search a bit on the topic (SQL PASSWORD, java).
- Every statement one after another, though I think the examples were contrived. In this way they stay open the shortest time, and least parallel. Reduces number of handles on database side.